# Are extra sub-tags for biblatex needed?

Tags: discussion, tagging

`biblatex` is the modern tool for bibliography creation you
really might want to use when writing your thesis. You can quite
easily change the appearance of your bibliography; you can change
the punctuation between fields, you can change the format of a
field, you can change the order of the fields.
You can even
define completely new fields and entry types, making it possible
to handle a database of different addresses for serial letter
creation.

Many question on site deal with at least one change of the above
mentioned list. So far all those questions are tagged {biblatex}.
This makes it a bit hard for helpers as well as starters to find
some relevant information that could have been categorized.

Do you think that a few additional tags are useful to better find
similar questions and answers?
Tags i could think of would be
(for example) called {biblatex-punct}, {biblatex-format}, or
{biblatex-order} (not to confuse with `sort`).

Comment: I wonder if such sub-tags might be for bibliographies in general. Things like 'ordering', 'punctuation' are common BibTeX problems as well as `biblatex` ones.

Comment: @JosephWright Fair point.

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but the tags should be very carefully named, which is a lot harder than it seems. Also, abbreviations in tags isn't so helpful (`punct` vs. `punctuation`) They will automatically show up when people start typing them so explicit ones are better I think.

Comment: Also, one thing that can help tagging more generally is putting proper sub-tag suggestions with the main tag descriptions.

Comment: I think tagging itself is a hard task and only experienced users are likely to get it right. Retagging is done often on TeX.SX to better categorize a question. I think, you cannot blame a starter for not correcctly tagging due to a lack of knowledge.

Comment: I agree and I'm not blaming anyone,  but I think we can do more to help make tags clear to people. That's my only point.

Comment: @Johannes_B Some of the tags aren't clear to me even now and even though I stop to read their descriptions. I still end up guessing arbitrarily some of the time. So I do think there are issues generally with the tagging. It isn't just a lack of knowledge (of the site or the content) which causes questions to be inappropriately tagged. The tags themselves are often obscure at best.

Comment: @cfr At best, the tag info/wiki should clarify stuff, but often even that is misleading. See for example the info for `template` and the recent question by peter about what a template is. Improving the quality of tag wikis might be another topic.

Comment: Anything @lockstep says I humbly agree :)

Comment: :-) agreed to that.